# How do you retrieve a Method object given its name and the type of its formal parameters?

Tags: java, reflection

Given

```
class Foo {
    public static void aa() {}
    public static void bb(String x) {}
}
```

The call:

```
Foo.class.getMethod("aa")
```

will return a reference to `aa`.

What incantation is necessary to get a reference to `bb`?

Comment: Are you looking to get a `Method` object for the `bb` method that declares a `String` parameter?  What is `method`? Do you mean `getMethod`? What does the javadoc of that method say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Foo.class.getMethod("bb", String.class);
```